# Worklight 5.0.6 - failing installation and update, filesize NaN

Tags: android-emulator, ibm-mobilefirst

Worklight Studion Version: 5.0.6, Build ID: IWSO506-I20130307_1415
Running on Windows 7

Testing in Android 4.0.2 emulator.

Had a little application been incrementally changing the CSS and redeploying suddenly I am getting a failure first to Direct Update and having uninstalled the app from the emulator fail to install the application. The install appears to work, launches and displays the splash screen but then decides that it needs to do a Direct Update, even though the app has just been deployed afresh, the direct update then fails. The update dialogue shows filesize NaN.

No errors in WL server console or Android console.

I'm inferring that my project has not built correctly, I've tried cleaning the project and rebuilding. Same effect. My next step will be to create a new project and gradually migrate my code over there, however I'd welcome any suggestions how to recover from this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to get Direct Update notification is when the checksum value of the application (.apk) you're trying to install, differs from the checksum value stored to the database upon build time.

Try deleting from your Eclipse workspace the folder "WorklightServerHome" (essentially, deleting the development filesytem-based database). Then try again to build and deploy the app, followed by launching it on the simulator.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. It was necessary to stop the server, and possibly would have been best to stop Eclipse in order to ensure that all files were closed so that they could be deleted. Then the initial rebuild of the project failed with messages indicating that expected files were not present (no surprise, they had just been deleted) but a second rebuild then worked just fine.